# Malformed lines in sources.list - how can I correct them?

Tags: apt

I am facing a problem with `/etc/apt/sources.list`

The 52nd line appears to be malformed

Line 52: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precisepartner`

Line 53: `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precisepartner`

This problem has caused Synaptic Package Manager and Ubuntu Software Center to not function properly and close abruptly.

Comment: Please don't edit such system files if you don't know what you're doing. If you need to add repositories use either the GUI or add files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` *directory* by adding a new file.

Answer (score 5):

Line 52 and 53 should be:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

Note the missing `ubuntu` subpath and the missing space between `precise` and `partner`. (line numbers as for your situation, not in general)